# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs

I have configured a single node cluster and its is running fine unexpectedly I got the below error and it stopped working. All the hadoop paths are configured in their paths but still I'm getting this error how to come out of this.

---

> /opt/hadoop/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 24: /bin/basename: cannot execute binary file
>
> /opt/hadoop/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: line 29: /bin/basename: cannot execute binary file
>
> Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell

Comment: Did you get this error when you tried to run a specific command or is it in logs?

Comment: while running any hadoop command like hadoop fs -ls and other any hadoop commands  im getting this error.  The HDFS is not accessible nor hive and anything

Comment: what is your Hadoop version?

Comment: Did you check whether you have `hadoop-core-*.jar` and `hadoop-common-*.jar` file?

Comment: @SAM my vesion is 1.2.x

Comment: @RajeshN, can u tell me what are the things i have to check once in those jars

Comment: Your error is displayed since it cant find the `hadoop-common-*.jar` and `hadoop-core-*.jar` files in your classpath. Add these jars in your classpath. Which command results this error?